# Getting weird Internal Service Error from my API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, multer

I created registration form in React JS in the client side that allows users to not only submit their details (aka username, email, etc.), but also upload an image for their profile picture.

However, every time the form is submitted, the following error appears:

> POST http://localhost/auth/register 500 (Internal Server Error)

> SubmitRegistration error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "JSON

The form is written below:

```
<form
    onSubmit={(evt) => {
        RegistrationForm = document.getElementById('RegistrationForm');
        NameInput = document.querySelector('#nameInput')
        EmailInput = document.querySelector('#emailInput')
        PasswordInput = document.querySelector('#passwordInput')
        ConfirmInput = document.querySelector('#confirm_passwordInput')
        ProfileInput = document.querySelector("#profile_picInput")
        var FormElements = {
            RegistrationForm,
            NameInput,
            EmailInput,
            PasswordInput,
            ConfirmInput,
        }
        HandleSignUpSubmit(evt, FormElements, profileImage, registerURL, dispatchFunctions, resetErrorFields)
    }}
    id="RegistrationForm"
    encType="multipart/form-data"
    className={`bg-[#f2e798] w-11/12 md:w-9/12 mx-auto lg:w-6/12 mt-[20px] py-10`}>
    <div
        id="Shell"
        className={`w-11/12 mx-auto ${FormStyle}`}
    >
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
            <input
                name="username"
                id="nameInput"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Type your username here"
                required
                className=""
                value={name}
                onChange={(evt) => onChangeHandler(evt, setName, resetErrorFields)}
            />
            <div id="usernameError" className="ErrorDiv">
                {usernameError != null && usernameError.length > 0 && RenderError(usernameError)}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input
                name="email"
                id="emailInput"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Type your email here"
                required
                className=""
                value={email}
                onChange={(evt) => onChangeHandler(evt, setEmail, resetErrorFields)}
            />
            <div id="emailError" className="ErrorDiv">
                {emailError != null && emailError.length > 0 && RenderError(emailError)}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="profile_pic">Profile picture</label>
            <input
                name="profile_pic"
                id="profile_picInput"
                type="file"
                placeholder="Upload an image htmlFor your your profile picture here"
                className="file:rounded-lg file:font-['DecoTech'] file:bg-[#99cbae] file:text-white cursor-pointer"
                onChange={(evt) => { HandleFileChange(evt, setImage) }}
            />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="password">password</label>
            <input
                name="password"
                id="passwordInput"
                type="password"
                placeholder="Type your password here"
                required
                className=""
                value={password}
                onChange={(evt) => onChangeHandler(evt, setPassword, resetErrorFields)}
            />
            <div id="passwordError" className="ErrorDiv">
                {passwordError != null && passwordError.length > 0 && RenderError(passwordError)}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="confirm_password">Confirm your password</label>
            <input
                name="confirm_password"
                id="confirm_passwordInput"
                type="password"
                placeholder="Re-type your password here to confirm"
                required
                className=""
                value={confirmPass}
                onChange={(evt) => onChangeHandler(evt, setConfirmPass, resetErrorFields)}
            />
            <div
                id="confirmError"
                className="ErrorDiv">
                {confirmError != null && confirmError.length > 0 && RenderError(confirmError)}

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ButtonWrapper"
            className="grid sm:flex"
        >
            <button
                type="submit"
                className={SubmitStyle}
                value="Submit"
            >Submit</button>
            <button
                type="button"
                className={CancelStyle}
                value="Cancel"
                onClick={useCallback(() => navigate(-1))}
            >Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <hr className="my-[25px] h-[2px] border-[2px]" />
        <h2 className="my-10 text-center text-lg">Already have an account with us?</h2>
        <button
            type="button"
            className="block rounded-full p-[10px] active:translate-x-[5px] active:translate-y-[5px] cursor-pointer border-white border-2 text-center w-[150px] select-none text-black mx-auto hover:bg-[#d48518] bg-[#e48f1a] text-center"
            onClick={useCallback(() => GoSignIn(navigate), [navigate])}
        >Log In</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The following hook handles the onChange event of the file input that allows the user to upload the image on the form:

```
  function HandleFileChange(evt, setImage) {
        const file = evt.target.files[0]; 
        const reader = new FileReader(); 
        reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
        reader.onload = () => {
            setImage(reader.result);
        }
    }
```

The following hook handles sending the Fetch request. FormData is used to passed the submitted.

```
//apiURL = "http://localhost/auth/register"
async function SubmitRegistration(data, apiURL, dispatchFunctions) {
    console.log("Registrating user")
    const {
        username,
        email,
        password,
        confirm_password,
        profile_pic,
    } = data;
    console.log("profile_pic: ", profile_pic)
    const formData = new FormData;
    formData.append("username", username);
    formData.append("email", email);
    formData.append("password", password);
    formData.append("confirm_password", confirm_password);
    formData.append("profile_pic", profile_pic);
    for (var key of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1])
    }
    const {
        GoHome,
        toggleDisplayAccountLink,
        setNewUser,
    } = dispatchFunctions;

    await fetch(apiURL, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        body: formData
    })
        .then(async response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log("Registration is successful.")
                await response.json()
                    .then(data => {
                        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data.user))
                        localStorage.setItem('token', data.token)
                        //setNewUser and toggleDisplayAccoutLink updates the header bar to contain
                        //data about the logged in user
                        setNewUser(data.user)
                        toggleDisplayAccountLink(true),
                            GoHome();

                    })
            }
            else {
                const result = await response.json()
                console.log("Registration failed with status code: ", result.error)
                RenderErrorArray(result.error, dispatchFunctions)
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("SubmitRegistration error: ", error)
        })
}
```

On the server side, the route is set as the following:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "public/uploads")
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        const filename = `${Date.now()}-${file.filename}${ext}`;
        cb(null, filename)
    }
});  

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }); 

router.post('/register', cors(), upload.single('profile_pic'), authController.Register)
```

The controller function that handles the POST request is written as the following:

```
exports.Register = [
    body("username")
        .trim()
        .isLength({ min: 1 })
        .withMessage("You must type your username.")
        .escape(),
    body("email")
        .trim()
        .isLength({ min: 1 })
        .withMessage("You must type your email address. ")
        .custom((value) => {
            if (!checkEmail(value)) {
                throw new Error("The email format is not valid. It must be something along the lines of Bob@email.com.");
            }
            return true;
        }),
    body("password")
        .trim()
        .isLength({ min: 4 })
        .withMessage("Your password must be at least 4 characters long."),
    body("profile_pic"),
    body("confirm_password")
        .trim()
        .isLength({ min: 4 })
        .withMessage("Your confirmation password must be at least 4 characters long.")
        .custom((value, { req }) => {
            if (value != req.body.password) {
                throw new Error("Your password and confirmation password should match.")
            }
            //this is necessary to indicate that the validation passed
            return true
        }),
    async (req, res, next) => {
        const {
            username,
            email,
        } = req.body;

        const errors = validationResult(req);

        const UserList = await User.find({})

        UserList.forEach(val => {
            if (val.username == username.trim()) {
                const obj = {
                    param: "username",
                    msg: "That username already exists in our database."
                }
                errors.errors.push(obj)
            }
            if (val.email.toLowerCase() == email.trim().toLowerCase()) {
                const obj = {
                    param: "email",
                    msg: "That email already exists in our database."
                }
                errors.errors.push(obj)
            }
        })

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: errors.array() });
        }
        try {
            const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
            const obj = {
                username: username.replace(/\s/g, ''),
                email: email,
                password: hashedPassword,
                joinedDate: Date.now(),
            }

            if (req.files && req.files.profile_pic) {
                obj.profile_pic = req.files.profile_pic[0].buffer
            }

            const newUser = new User(obj);
            const result = await newUser.save();

            const savedUser = {
                username: result.username,
                email: result.email,
                joinedDate: result.joinedDate,
                profile_pic: result.profile_pic,
                id: result._id,
            }

            console.log("User is successfully created.")
            const token = jwt.sign(savedUser.toJSON(), process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: 60 * 60 })
            return res.status(200).json({ user: savedUser, token, message: "User is successfully saved in the database" });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error in trying to create new user: ", e.message)
            res.status(500).json({ error: e.message });
        }
    }
]
```

I have been stuck on this problem for quite a long time and I appreciate any help I can get from here.

Answer (score 1):

There is too much input data and it is quite hard to give the answer for sure. However, `error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "JSON` is a clear indication that your server returns HTML (or XML) as a response instead of JSON that you expect

Since you see 500 error code it means that the issue is server and it is not related to the request/UI code. There are infinite number of reasons why this might be the issue (e.g. db connection issues, permission issues, etc.)

To investigate it further you need to

1. Check real output of the POST request. If your server is a dev build it usually includes all related information. You can see actual response in Chrome DevTools in the Network tab
2. If there is no data available in the response you can check server logs

Comment: Thank you for your response.

From what you said, I realize that the API was not handling errors correctly and was rendering an HTML file. So, the controller function threw an error, the HTML file was being rendered, which is why I got the error I mentioned. 

After correcting that issue, the true error is shown and read as  ""Multipart: Boundary not found".

It has something to do with the fact that the headers of the fetch request is set to the following :

            headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },